# Typhoon storyboard integration with manual assembly activation

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

I have a problem with Typhoon. I want to use storyboard integration, so I set the correct name of storyboard in plist and defined 'typhoonKey' runtime arguments for each view controller in storyboard. It works very well when I had assemblies activated throught plist integration. But my problem is that I want to manually activate assembly now because I have to setup MagicalRecord first (I want to inject model to view controller, and that model uses MagicalRecord).

In `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

method I called

`TyphoonAssembly *viewControllersAssembly = [[ViewControllersAssembly new] activate];`

but it doesn't work. It is possible to use typhoon storyboard integration with manually activated assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually instantiate a TyphoonStoryboard, and if you wish you can create a definition for this storyboard in your assembly. From here you can instantiate a view controller (probably the initial one) from that storyboard, and because its a `TyphoonStoryboard` dependencies will be injected.

The drawback to this approach is that UIStateRestoration doesn't work as expected - this was the initial problem that led us to develop plist integration style of bootstrapping Typhoon.

So you could:

- Manually instantiate, as long as you don't need UIStateRestoration.
- Look for another way to handle your life-cycle requirements.